# Average from distribution-fit vs sample average

Tags: distributions, outliers, fitting, mean, moments

If I know the functional form of a distribution, is it better to fit the distribution to the data to find the mean, or is it better to just look at sample average.

I know sample average is the unbiased estimator of the mean, but I feel like fitting to a known distribution may reduce the effect of outliers. Is that true?

If not, is there a way to use the information about the shape of distribution to find a better estimation of the mean? What about other moments?

**Edit** By fitting the distribution to the data, what I had in mind was something like FindDistributionParameter function in Mathematica. This is what it does:

The maximum likelihood method attempts to maximize the log-likelihood function $\sum\log(f(x_i;\theta))$, where $\theta$ are the distribution parameters and $f(x_i;\theta)$ is the PDF of the symbolic distribution.

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense. For example, if you fit the distribution by method of moments you will always get the same answer  (by definition). More generally, even with other methods of fitting the distribution you will often get the same answer (e.g., you will struggle to fit a normal or Poisson distribution with a different mean to the sample mean).

Comment: @Tim I added some explanation about what I had in mind. Does the maximum likelihood method have the same problem?

Comment: well, in the case of maximum likelihood for a normal distribution, you should get the same mean (within numeric precision), but a different standard deviation, as the maximum likelihood estimate is biased (divides by n rather than n - 1).  If you are worried about outliers, the trick is to use a robust method, such as a trimmed mean or median. I'm pretty confident that there is nothing to be gained in fitting distributions to improve your estimation of the mean. The mean is the mean...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the MATLAB code below:

```
clear; close all; rng(1)
ntrials = 1000;
nsamples = 10000;

%% beta distribution: true mean 0.9

xbetamu = nan(ntrials, 1);
xbetapmu = nan(ntrials, 1);
for i = 1:ntrials
    xbeta = betarnd(90, 10, nsamples, 1);
    xbetap = betapdf(xbeta, 90, 10);

    xbetamu(i) = mean(xbeta);
    xbetapmu(i) = sum(xbeta.*xbetap)/sum(xbetap);
end

figure; hist([xbetamu xbetapmu], 100)
title('beta distribution')
legend('sample mean', 'pdf mean')

%% gamma distribution: true mean 4

xgammamu = nan(ntrials, 1);
xgammapmu = nan(ntrials, 1);
for i = 1:ntrials
    xgamma = gamrnd(2, 2, nsamples, 1);
    xgammap = gampdf(xgamma, 2, 2);

    xgammamu(i) = mean(xgamma);
    xgammapmu(i) = sum(xgamma.*xgammap)/sum(xgammap);
end

figure; hist([xgammamu xgammapmu], 100)
title('gamma distribution')
legend('sample mean', 'pdf mean')

%% normal: true mean 5

xnormmu = nan(ntrials, 1);
xnormpmu = nan(ntrials, 1);
for i = 1:ntrials
    xnorm = normrnd(5, 2, nsamples, 1);
    xnormp = normpdf(xnorm, 5, 2);

    xnormmu(i) = mean(xnorm);
    xnormpmu(i) = sum(xnorm.*xnormp)/sum(xnormp);
end

figure; hist([xnormmu xnormpmu], 100)
title('normal distribution')
legend('sample mean', 'pdf mean')

%% poisson: true mean 5

xpoismu = nan(ntrials, 1);
xpoispmu = nan(ntrials, 1);
for i = 1:ntrials
    xpois = poissrnd(5, nsamples, 1);
    xpoisp = poisspdf(xpois, 5);

    xpoismu(i) = mean(xpois);
    xpoispmu(i) = sum(xpois.*xpoisp)/sum(xpoisp);
end

figure; hist([xpoismu xpoispmu], 100)
title('poisson distribution')
legend('sample mean', 'pdf mean')
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

For any of the distributions with nonzero skewness, the distribution of the pdf-weighted means is shifted in the direction of the skewness with respect to the distribution of the sample mean. It also looks like it has a smaller variance. Here, we used the true parameter values of the distributions; it seems like fitting the distributions would only perform as well or worse since the fitting process itself requires using the samples.

The statement that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator of the mean holds regardless of the distribution of the data:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\bar{x}] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[x_i] = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\theta = \frac{n\theta}{n} = \theta
\end{align}
Since this doesn't depend on the distribution of the data, your estimate will always be unbiased.

On the other hand, if you have outliers, there's a chance you could grossly mis-estimate your mean if you don't have knowledge of the functional form of the distribution (see code and figures below).

```
%% normal with outliers: true mean somewhere above 5

xnormmu = nan(ntrials, 1);
xnormpmu = nan(ntrials, 1);
for i = 1:ntrials
    xnorm = normrnd(5, 2, nsamples, 1);
    if logical(binornd(1, 0.1, 1))
        xnorm = [xnorm; 20000];
    else
        xnorm = [xnorm; normrnd(5, 2, 1, 1)];
    end    

    xnormp = normpdf(xnorm, 5, 2);

    xnormmu(i) = mean(xnorm);
    xnormpmu(i) = sum(xnorm.*xnormp)/sum(xnormp);
end

figure; hist([xnormmu xnormpmu], 100)
title('normal distribution with outliers')
legend('sample mean', 'pdf mean')

%% poisson with outliers: true mean somewhere above 5

xpoismu = nan(ntrials, 1);
xpoispmu = nan(ntrials, 1);
for i = 1:ntrials
    xpois = poissrnd(5, nsamples, 1);
    if logical(binornd(1, 0.1, 1))
        xpois = [xpois; 20000];
    else
        xpois = [xpois; poissrnd(5, 1, 1)];
    end

    xpoisp = [poisspdf(xpois, 5)];

    xpoismu(i) = mean(xpois);
    xpoispmu(i) = sum(xpois.*xpoisp)/sum(xpoisp);
end

figure; hist([xpoismu xpoispmu], 100)
title('poisson distribution with outliers')
legend('sample mean', 'pdf mean')
```

[image]
[image]

Here, 0.1 is the probability of having an outlier in your dataset. Approximately 10% of the sample-mean estimates of the population mean are much farther from the true mean than the pdf-weighted estimates. In this case, knowledge of the true distribution more frequently results in a better estimate of the population mean than just using the sample mean. The sample mean is still ``unbiased'' (because you have to weight the means of the datasets with and without outliers to get the true mean, which is no longer just 5 in either of the two above cases). However, since you know that outliers exist and that their values are inflating the mean (which is actually 5), the sample estimate is much worse on average compared to the pdf-fitted mean.

Comment: Why is the pdf-weighted mean the same as mean of a fit to the sample?

Comment: My plots show the distribution of pdf-weighted means. What do you mean by mean of a fit to the sample?

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I understand your comment now. Mathematically, my PDF-weighted mean should have the same expectation as the empirical mean, but I can't figure out why it doesn't experimentally. I also don't think it necessarily is equal to the mean of a fit to the sample, so my answer is pretty flawed. Can you clarify what you mean by "better"? I think, ultimately, it comes down to the bias-variance tradeoff, but let me know.